# How to make a range of points on a graph i n r a different colour

Tags: r, colors

I have made a graph with the year on the x-axis and sea level rise on  the y-axis.
I am trying to make the data from 2025 (predictions) a different colour to that before 2025.
I have grouped and labeled the predicted data using this code and have also included the code for my graph

> predictions=data[which(data$Year>2024 & data$Year<2121),]
> plot(data$Sea.Level..cm.~data$Year,xlab="Year",ylab="Sea Level (cm)",pch=21,col=c("Blue"))

How do I go from here in making the predictions red but the previous data blue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a command `points(predictions$.., ...., col="red")`. It will add points to the previous `plot`.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Toy data used.

```
vec <- c( rep(2001,10), rep(2002, 3) )

tf <- (vec < 2002) + 1

barplot( 1:length(vec), vec, col=c("red","blue")[tf], names=vec )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a vector of colours to plot in the *col* argument. For example, following your existing syntax:

```
predictions <- rep("red", nrow(data))
predictions[which(data$Year>2024 & data$Year<2121)] <- "blue"
plot(data$Sea.Level..cm.~data$Year,xlab="Year",ylab="Sea Level (cm)",pch=21,col=predictions)
```